# FFProbe output timebase only

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, encoding, ffprobe

When running ffprobe, it displays a lot more data than I need. I've already included the -hide_banner flag and its helped clean it up, but more specifically I only need the tbn
Is there a way to limit the output to only display as little as possible?

This part of the output:
28771 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, **2997 tbn**, 29.97 tbc (default)

Comment: Not sure, but you can 'pipe' it to another command (like `find` in Windows) to get JUST the chunk you need. Give us your OS version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to only print a stream's timebase is

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -show_entries stream=time_base -select_streams v:0 INPUT
```

This will print the time_base only for the first video stream, e.g.

```
1/90000
```

Comment: Thats exactly it!! Thank you so much!